# Prototype js How to make periodical Updater hide element of a class based on ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I am doing a periodical Updater with prototype js and i would like to  make it hide every element of the page having the `class='robot'` based on the response sent by the ajax request. If the response is equal to `hidethemall` i want every `class='robot'`to be hidden but if it is not, then we do nothing and perform no update

So far I was able to make my function reset after a number of periodical update in order not to load the server. So far this is how my function looks like

```
function mettreajour_periodique(span_id, url_traitement, nos_parametres,
         our_frequency, our_decay, our_decay_to_reset)
{
    var ajax = new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater({success: span_id}, url_traitement,
    {
        method:'get',
        frequency: our_frequency,
        decay: our_decay,
        parameters: nos_parametres,
        evalScripts: true,
        onSuccess: function(r) { //or onComplete
            if (ajax.decay >= our_decay_to_reset) 
            {
                ajax.decay = our_decay;
            }
        }
    });
}

mettreajour_periodique('nombre_nouveaux_messages',
    'messages_compter_non_lus_actualise.php', '&membre=lesucces', 10, 2, 1800);
```

**Questions**

How to stop this from Updating the div and rather make it hide every div with the class `class='robot'` if the ajax response is equal to `hidethemall` ?

Comment: PeriodicalUpdater already does a decay function based on whatever the reply is. If the reply is the same as the last request, it increments the delay, and the moment that the reply is different, it resets the delay. So a bunch of the code above is (apparently) redundant. As to your question, have you tried just putting `$$('.robot').invoke('hide');` in there? That would hide everything with that classname.

Comment: @Walter Please but where am i supposed to put `$$('.robot').invoke('hide');` ? Is it after `onSuccess: function(r)` ?

Comment: Inside the onSuccess method body, so it runs only after success.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater` is it uses `Ajax.Updater` which expects to put the response somewhere and that is not what you want to do.  So I would define a new class instead.

```
Ajax.PeriodicalHider = Class.create(Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater, {
    initialize: function($super, selector, url, options) {
        $super(null, url, options);
        // selector are the elements to hide
        this.selector = selector;
        // max_decay is for extra time control
        this.max_decay = this.options.max_decay;
    },

    onTimerEvent: function() {
        // use a Request instead of an Updater
        this.updater = new Ajax.Request(this.url, this.options);
    },

    updateComplete: function($super, response) {
        $super(response);
        if (this.max_decay) {
            // not accurate, a new timer already has the wrong frequency
            this.decay = Math.min(this.decay, this.max_decay);
        }
        if (response.responseText == 'hidethemall') {
            $$(this.selector).each(Element.hide);
            // stop now because there is no more to do
            this.stop();
        }
    }
});

new Ajax.PeriodicalHider('.robot', 'messages_compter_non_lus_actualise.php', {
    method: 'get',
    frequency: 10,
    decay: 2,
    max_decay: 1800,
    parameters: '&membre=lesucces'
});
```

This has been [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/5th9o1j1/1/).

Comment: Well, yes. Jsfiddle changed how their endpoint works which broke the script but back when it was relevant it definitely worked.